# Issue running code sniffer on Mac

Tags: php, phpcodesniffer

I am trying to install php code sniffer. I have manage to get to a point where after running 
`php /Users/ryanfernandes/pear/bin/phpcs --version` it display the info. but when I try to run code sniffer by

```
php /Users/username/pear/bin/phpcs /Users/username/development/htdocs/test.php 
PHP Warning:  fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Users/username/pear/share/pear/PHP/CodeSniffer/Reporting.php on line 155

Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Users/username/pear/share/pear/PHP/CodeSniffer/Reporting.php on line 155
PHP Warning:  stream_get_meta_data() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Users/username/pear/share/pear/PHP/CodeSniffer/Reporting.php on line 206

Warning: stream_get_meta_data() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Users/username/pear/share/pear/PHP/CodeSniffer/Reporting.php on line 206
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in /Users/username/pear/share/pear/PHP/CodeSniffer/Reporting.php on line 208

Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in /Users/username/pear/share/pear/PHP/CodeSniffer/Reporting.php on line 208
PHP Warning:  fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Users/username/pear/share/pear/PHP/CodeSniffer/Reporting.php on line 209

Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Users/username/pear/share/pear/PHP/CodeSniffer/Reporting.php on line 209
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You need to solve each issue in turn which means learning to troubleshoot each issue. Without code we cannot help you.

Comment: check the current directory is readable and writeable. (Check permisions)

Answer (score 1):

From the error messages, it looks like you are using PHP_CodeSniffer version 1.5.4. PHP_CodeSniffer uses the tmpfile() function to create a temporary file. The directory that it is created in can be found by running:

```
php -r 'echo sys_get_temp_dir().PHP_EOL;'
```

Make sure you are allowed to write to that directory because the tmpfile() method is obviously returning FALSE, which most commonly happens if the directory is not writable.

Comment: Hi Greg, Thanks for your reply. After giving read write permission it worked. Thanks again. Another question, each time now I have to run code sniffer i have to do the following                                    php /Users/username/pear/bin/phpcs /Users/username/development/htdocs/test/test-cs.php                       instead of                                                              phpcs /Users/ryanfernandes/development/htdocs/ryan/test-cs.php         Any help appreciated.

Comment: This would be because the PEAR executable directory (where PEAR puts scripts like phpcs) is not in your PATH. Run `pear config-show | grep bin_dir` to find that directory (e.g., /ur/local/bin). Now edit `~/.profile` (create it if it doesn't exit) and add the line `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` and save. If you are already exporting the PATH there, just add the PEAR executable path to it instead (paths are separated by colons). Reload your profile by running `. ~/.profile` and the phpcs command should work.

Comment: Hi Greg, Thanks again. After running pear config-show | grep bin_dir, I got this /Users/username/pear/bin. I already have .bash_profile with the following export PATH=$PATH:/Users/username/pear/bin/pear:/usr/local/zend/bin:/Users/username/pear/bin                                                              I am not sure if .profile and .bash_profile are the same. Also, if I do pear config-show I get the following                                                                                      Thanks

Comment: =====================================
Auto-discover new Channels     auto_discover    <not set>
Default Channel                default_channel  pear.php.net
HTTP Proxy Server Address      http_proxy       <not set>
PEAR server [DEPRECATED]       master_server    pear.php.net
Default Channel Mirror         preferred_mirror pear.php.net
Remote Configuration File      remote_config    <not set>
PEAR executables directory     bin_dir          /Users/username/pear/bin

Comment: PEAR documentation directory   doc_dir          /Users/username/pear/docs
PHP extension directory        ext_dir          /usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions
PEAR directory                 php_dir          /Users/username/pear/share/pear
PEAR Installer cache directory cache_dir        /usr/local/zend/tmp/pear/cache
PEAR configuration file        cfg_dir          /Users/username/pear/cfg
directory
PEAR data directory            data_dir         /Users/username/pear/data
PEAR Installer download        download_dir     /tmp/pear/install
directory

Comment: PHP CLI/CGI binary             php_bin          /usr/local/zend/bin/php
php.ini location               php_ini          /usr/local/zend/etc/php.ini
--program-prefix passed to     php_prefix       <not set>
PHP's ./configure
--program-suffix passed to     php_suffix       <not set>
PHP's ./configure
PEAR Installer temp directory  temp_dir         /tmp/pear/install
PEAR test directory            test_dir         /Users/username/pear/tests                                            PEAR www files directory       www_dir          /Users/username/pear/www

Comment: Cache TimeToLive               cache_ttl        3600
Preferred Package State        preferred_state  stable
Unix file mask                 umask            22
Debug Log Level                verbose          1
PEAR password (for             password         <not set>
maintainers)
Signature Handling Program     sig_bin          /usr/local/bin/gpg
Signature Key Directory        sig_keydir       /usr/local/zend/etc/pearkeys
Signature Key Id               sig_keyid        <not set>
Package Signature Type         sig_type         gpg

Comment: PEAR username (for             username         <not set>
maintainers)
User Configuration File        Filename         /Users/username/.pearrc
System Configuration File      Filename         /usr/local/zend/etc/pear.conf

Comment: If phpcs is already in your path, then what happens when you try and run the command? Does it just say "command not found"? Does `which phpcs` produce any output? Does `echo $PATH` show you the correct path in there? If all that looks good, then I'm not sure what else to try.